# VBA: I keep getting an error related to object variable not set properly

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set this simple code but no matter what I do, I always get an error 'object required' on the line:

> Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(What:=searchValue, LookIn:=xlValues)

My source code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit
'I'm going to let the program search for the date in the pre-filled date -> select the entire row & column below -> move it down by 1 row -> insert the date above the moved pre-filled date -> fill other details
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim submittedDate As Date
    Dim searchValue As Variant
    Dim searchRange As Variant
    Dim foundCell As Range
    
    Set ws = Sheet1 'setting it up so that I'm dealing with Sheet1
    ws.Range("A7:A37").NumberFormat = "dd-mmm" 'setting the number format of the values in A7:A37 as dd-mmm
    submittedDate = Me.TextBox1.Value 'setting the input value as a variable
    searchValue = submittedDate
    searchRange = ws.Range("A7:A37")
    Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(What:=searchValue, LookIn:=xlValues)
    
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Value found!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Value not found..."
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Any thoughts/help would be appreciated and thank you in advance!

I can't seem to think of anything as a solution, as all the variables are declared ...

Comment: The value of an Excel date is 1234.5678 and not a human readable date 22/01/2023 so the search will never succeed.

Comment: Have you debugged your code at all? What is the value of `searchRange` on the line you pointed out? If it is not the range you expect it to be, that means you need to change `searchRange = ws.Range("A7:A37")` to `Set searchRange = ws.Range("A7:A37")` (I have only very quickly read the code, not checked for sure I am pointing to the correct answer here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Find()` method of the `Range` class needs a `Range` object to be called on, while

```
searchRange = ws.Range("A7:A37")
```

would result in a `searchRange` as an array storing the values of the cells "A7:A37", since the default property of the `Range` object is the `Value` one (it's as if you had coded `searchRange.Value = ws.Range("A7:A37")`.

While in order to have a `Range` object you have to use the `Set` keyword

```
Set searchRange = ws.Range("A7:A37")
```

That said, you'd also better declare `searchRange` as of `Range` type

```
Dim searchRange As Range
```

which would have originated an error for `Set searchRange = ws.Range("A7:A37")` in the compiling phase, instead of the one you experienced in the runtime one

Finally, you can omit the declaration and use of `submittedDate` variable and go direct with the `searchValue` one only

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim searchValue As Variant
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim foundCell As Range
    
    Set ws = Sheet1 'setting it up so that I'm dealing with Sheet1
    ws.Range("A7:A37").NumberFormat = "dd-mmm" 'setting the number format of the values in A7:A37 as dd-mmm
    searchValue = Me.TextBox1.Value 'setting the input value as a variable
    Set searchRange = ws.Range("A7:A37")
    Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(What:=searchValue, LookIn:=xlValues)
    
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Value found!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Value not found..."
    End If
    
End Sub
```

A more condensed version of which is the following one:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim foundCell As Range
    With Sheet1.Range("A7:A37") ' reference the needed range
        .NumberFormat = "dd-mmm" 'setting the number format of the values in referenced range as dd-mmm
        Set foundCell = .Find(What:=Me.TextBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues) 'search for the TextBox1 value in the referenced range values
    End With
        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Value found!"
        Else
            MsgBox "Value not found..."
        End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your in-depth explanation. 
I read and scrutinized your response and it seems like the error came from my lack of understanding in setting the correct data types. I'm just starting to properly learn VBA and I certainly lack fundamentals. Do you recommend any books for studying the basics  of VBA? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still getting used to the site. I just accepted your answer! Thank you again! :)

Comment: I have an issue... at first, it was working fine, however, I do not know what changed but now the search result comes out to be randomly Value found or Not found. Sometimes it works properly but sometimes it suddenly stops working and always gives out 'Value not found' for whatever reason. I am not sure what's causing this..

Comment: as per this site rules, you'd better post a new question, attaching the code you're actually using and the data scenario originating the issue

Comment: ok I will do that.

Comment: yes, please. and be sure to give a proper picture: you're talking about "Iterations" which were not in this thread subject

Comment: Sorry, I thought iteration meant just running a code!